# Assigning values to an Object, automatically updates existing Objects stored in an array

Tags: javascript, angular

I need some help please. I have a simple Angular app that takes some form input values. These values get passed to a simple method, where the values are assigned to the matching property values of an object. Finally this object is pushed into an array.

**My problem is this**; every time the values passed into the method are assigned to the my object's property values, all other objects' (already in my array) properties gets updated as well.

What am I doing wrong(I believe this is going to be one of those coding bloopers I will fondly remember...one day)?

**My Code:**
**This is the object the values are assigned to:**

```
UOPSim: Sim = {
    simId: null,
    simType: '',
    imageUrl: '',
    simCustomName: '',
    simDescription_Line1: '',
    simDescription_Line2: '',
    simDescription_Line3: '',
    simDescription_Line4: '',
    peakGigLimit: null,
    peakAmount: null,
    monthlyGigLimit: null,
    monthlyAmount: null,
};
```

**This is my method:**

```
onAddSimToCart(sim) {
    if (sim.simType === 'UOP') {
      this.UOPSim.simId = this.simsInCart.length + 1;
      this.UOPSim.simType = sim.simType;
      this.UOPSim.simCustomName = sim.simCustomName;
      this.UOPSim.peakGigLimit = sim.peakGigLimit;
      this.UOPSim.peakAmount = sim.peakAmount;
      this.UOPSim.monthlyGigLimit = sim.monthlyGigLimit;
      this.UOPSim.monthlyAmount = sim.monthlyAmount;
      this.simsInCart.push(this.UOPSim);
    } else {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you are using one variable that you are pushing in an array, the same object over and over.

Comment: `this.simsInCart` is just an array containing multiple references to the same object, `this.UOPSim`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone happens upon this question, this is how I resolved my issue:

As per @mbojko answer that was posted, I was simply referencing the same Object (newb move!).

**I solved this by simply doping the following:**

If you want shallow copy, use Object.assign({}, a)

For "deep" copy, use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))

***Thanks to @Tareq for his answer to the post here: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)**

So in my case I changed `this.simsInCart.push(this.UOPSim);` to:

```
const newSim = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.UOPSim));
this.simsInCart.push(newSim);
```

Answer (score -1):

Angular and TypeScript have nothing to do with that. It's simple JavaScript:

```
      this.simsInCart.push(this.UOPSim);
```

If the components keep one `UOPSim`, then you don't have *n* objects in your array, you have *n* references to the same object.

You can clone it one way or another:

```
      this.simsInCart.push({ ...this.UOPSim });
```